# Shouldn't ℵ₀ be the cardinality of the reals?

Tags: set-theory, real-numbers, cardinals

If in ZFC any set can be well ordered, and that $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of every infinite set that can be well ordered, shouldn't $\aleph_0$ be the cardinality of the real numbers?

I know this isn't true, but I do not know why.

EDIT: $\aleph_0$ is NOT the cardinality of every infinite set that can be well ordered.

Comment: $\aleph_0$ is certainly not the cardinality of every infinite set that can be well-ordered! Where did you get that idea?

Comment: The integers is infinite and can be well-ordered.  So it should refer to the cardinality of the integers before it refers to the cardinality of the reals.

Comment: @TonyK Wikipedia about Aleph 0: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleph_number

Comment: That article doesn't say that at all.

Comment: @Randall "[...] the aleph numbers are a sequence of numbers used to represent the cardinality (or size) of infinite sets that can be well-ordered."

Comment: @fleablood Thank you for your answer, but then what did I misunderstood about what is written on wikipedia?

Comment: Right, but $\aleph_0$ is only one of those numbers.

Comment: @NathanKaufmann "aleph numbers", not "aleph zero". Aleph zero is one of alephs, the first one. But there are many many other alephs.

Comment: "In mathematics, particularly in set theory, the aleph numbers are a sequence of numbers used to represent the cardinality (or size) of infinite sets that can be well-ordered"  That doesn't mean there is only one such set and one such cardinality.  $\aleph_0$ is the least possible cardinality a well ordered set can have, $\aleph_1$ is the *next* possible cardinality that a well ordered set can have.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misread, thank you all for your time, next time I'll try to read better before asking a question.

Comment: Does it mean that the reals cardinality is one of the aleph numbers?

Comment: That is harder to answer explicitly.  Read about the [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis).  Suffice to say that in ZFC, yes the cardinality of the reals is $\aleph_1$, but you don't need to work in ZFC... you could work in ZF without C instead at which point $\aleph_1$ could correspond to something "inbetween" and the cardinality of the reals would be a larger aleph number.

Comment: @NathanKaufmann under the axiom of choice every cardinal number is an aleph. Of course it is not aleph zero. However whether it is aleph one or not is a different question though (continuum hypothesis).

Comment: @JMoravitz no, cardinality of reals is not (or does not have to be) $\aleph_1$ in ZFC. That is precisely continuum hypothesis which is independent of ZFC. ZFC stands for ZF + Axiom of Choice, not ZF + Continuum.

Comment: @JMoravitz Additionally, it's not true that if we drop choice then the continuum is bigger than $\aleph_1$. Even if choice fails for the reals, they can still be incomparable in size; e.g. this happens under AD.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If in ZFC any set can be well ordered

Correct.

> and that $\aleph_0$ is the cardinality of every infinite set that can be well ordered

No. Every infinite set has cardinality of some $\aleph$ (without zero). That's the correct statement. This btw requires full strength of ZFC, it is not true without C (the Axiom of Choice). Indeed, it is well known that $\mathbb{R}$ does not have to be well orderable in ZF (see this: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/5116/is-the-existence-of-a-well-ordering-on-r-independent-of-zf). And "being an aleph" pretty much means "being well orderable".

> shouldn't $\aleph_0$ be the cardinality of the real numbers?

It is well known to be false, e.g. the famous [Cantor's diagonal argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cantor%27s_diagonal_argument) shows that cardinality of reals is not $\aleph_0$. What is true is that cardinality of reals is $2^{\aleph_0}$. Also, as I mentioned earlier, under the Axiom of Choice $\mathbb{R}$ is well orderable, and so cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$ is some $\aleph$. The next $\aleph$ after $\aleph_0$ is $\aleph_1$. So it is a natural question to ask: is cardinality of reals $\aleph_1$? Or in symbols: does $2^{\aleph_0}=\aleph_1$ hold? This question is known as [continuum hypothesis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuum_hypothesis) and it is well known to be independent of ZFC. Meaning there are models of ZFC where it is true and there are models of ZFC where it is false.

Comment: Thank you very much! That answers most questions I've been asking myself lately.